# Hosting a metro apps inside desktop app

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am new to Win32 C++ programming.
Now, I want to create an application which is able to host a metro (AppContainer) app. It seems possible using these COM Interfaces :

- IApplicationDesignModeSettings ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj553506(v=vs.85).aspx))
- IApplicationActivationManager (used to launch the metro app)

I am able to launch an app normally using the IApplicationActivationManager, but to be able to host an app inside a window, the app need to be launched in design mode. To be able to launch an app in design mode, I need to setup the IApplicationDesignModeSettings, which needs the IInitializeWithWindow ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706981(v=vs.85).aspx)) to be initialized. The Initialize() method of the IInitializeWithWindow requires a "proxy window" hwnd. This is where my problem lies. I created a window using a standard CreateWindow() and an empty callback, use that window HWND as the IInitializeWithWindow->Initialize() parameter. But instead of returning S_OK, this method returns E_ACCESSDENIED error. Why is this happening? What does the "proxy window" means? What is the possible resolution?

Comment: I'm not really sure this is possible.

Comment: why :)  The interfaces you mention are, I presume, what Visual Studio and Blend use for purposes of building Windows Store Apps, hence design mode - are you building some type of add-on/testing framework?

Comment: The main purpose of this project is to satisfy my curiosity :D .
I know this is possible, because some has implemented this such as stardock's start8 and RetroUI pro.

Comment: It might help if you show your actual code. One thing I do notice is that `IApplicationDesignModeSettings` only allows `Initialize()` to be called once *per process*, so is it possible that something else in your app has already called `Initialize()` before you do? Or maybe your app needs to be run as an administrator, or maybe be code-signed, before `IApplicationDesignModeSettings` will allow your app to host a Metro app?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Here is the code [link](http://pastebin.com/UJiTs3mS). I called it once, and my app is in elevated mode (administrator). Yes, the app is unsigned.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the E_ACCESSDENIED problem still persists after signing the exe

Answer (score 0):

You cannot host a Metro App in a Desktop App due to the Windows 8 sandbox model.  Metro Apps are hosted by a special process (wwahost.exe) that leverages brokers to access system level resources.  Hosting a Metro App by any other processes means someone can play the "middle-man"  and sniff/manipulate system requests, which is an unacceptable risk.  On the other hand, you can host Metro Apps through individual VMs.